# SwiftUI: NavigationColumnState.boundPathChange(to:environment:) Navigation issue

Tags: swift, swiftui, path, swift-data

Every time I tap a navigation link in Calendar view it crashes. I am new to swift data so I'm not exactly sure how these things go...

I've tried to change the Variable names of ModelContext and Paths (you can see I still have path and second path, but it doesn't seem to want to work correctly.

This is how my CalendarView looks like

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    @Query var events: [EventsData]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var ModelContext
    @State private var secondPath = [EventsData] ()
    @State private var todaysDate = Date.now

    var body: some View {
       NavigationStack(path: $secondPath){
            Capsule(style: .continuous)
                 .fill(.secondary)
                 .frame(width: 160, height: 50)
                 .clipped()
                 .overlay {
                      Text("Add an event")
                         .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                  }
                 .onTapGesture {
                      addEvent()
                  }
                  .onTapGesture {
                      impactFeedback.impactOccurred()
                  }
              .navigationDestination(for: EventsData.self) { event in
                  NewEventView(event: event, calendar: Calendars)
               }
      }
      func addEvent() {
          let event = EventsData(name: "", calendar: "", date: "", color: "")
          ModelContext.insert(event)
          secondPath.append(event)
      }
      func deleteData(event: EventsData) {
          ModelContext.delete(event)
      }
      func deleteEvent(at offsets: IndexSet) {
          for offset in offsets {
              let event = events[offset]
              ModelContext.delete(event)
          }
      }
}
```

and here is my ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query var events: [EventsData]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @State private var path = [EventsData] ()
    @State private var todaysDate = Date.now
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack (path: $path) {
             Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                  .imageScale(.large)
                  .font(.title)
                  .onTapGesture{
                       addEvent()
                   }
              .navigationDestination(for: EventsData.self) { event in
                   NewEventView(event: event, calendar: Calendars)
              }
        }
    }
    func addEvent() {
        let event = EventsData(name: "", calendar: "", date: "", color: "")
        modelContext.insert(event)
        path.append(event)
    }
    func deleteData(event: EventsData) {
        modelContext.delete(event)
    }
    func deleteEvent(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            let event = events[offset]
            modelContext.delete(event)
        }
    }
}
```

EventsData is declared like this using swiftData

```
@Model
class EventsData {
    var name: String = ""
    var calendar: String = ""
    var color: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    
    init(name: String, calendar: String, date: String, color: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.calendar = calendar
        self.date = date
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

The connections between both the views are through a tab view at the bottom (in the MyAppApp.swift, instead of just launching content view, it launches navigation bar and that launches navigation view.

```
struct navigationBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            TabView {
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("At a glance", systemImage: "newspaper")
                    }
                CalendarView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Calendar", systemImage: "calendar")
                    }
                TasksView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Tasks", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
                    }
                settingsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As requested, the error itself, is that the navigation doesn't work and it ends up crashing and gives the the error

NavigationColumnState.boundPathChange(to:environment:)

and when debugging it also gives me the error
Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftUI.AnyNavigationPath.Error.comparisonTypeMismatch

which I think might be related...

I dropped the TestFlight link if you want to see the issue for yourself, maybe that might help as well!

[Testflight link](https://testflight.apple.com/join/n80QCcF1)

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. How does ContentView and CalendarView relate? How is EventsData defined? What error message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: Let me update it real quick!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. The tag information doesn't belong there at all, and *issue* is a meaningless problem description. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it's about. For help writing a better title, see [ask].